# User-agent line needed in robots.txt?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, robots.txt

I'm about to deploy a website for testing and I want to let all the indexing bots to not index my site during this phase.

According to [Google Webmasters Help section](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961) apparently you only need the following in your `robots.txt` file:

```
Disallow: /
```

But according to http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html and other sources you have to write it like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

I'm afraid that the bots still will index my site if I leave the `User-agent: *` part out.

So which is the proper way to do it?

Comment: read this > https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Comment: @user29671 Thanks, but the article doesn't specify User-agent anywhere.

Comment: actually, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original robots.txt specification is http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html, where it says:

> The record starts with one or more User-agent lines […]

So yes, `User-agent` is required.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and as far as I have search for it, there is no `robots.txt` documentation saying you can drop the user-agent line. I would not rely on this.